# javascript var or not var, what's the difference?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between using var and not using var in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript)

Hi All

Declaring`var myVar;` with `var` keyword or declaring `myVar` without it.

This might be a stupid question for some, but I'm in a learning process with javascript.

Sometime, when reading other people's code, I see that some variables are declared without the 'var' at the front. Just to emphasise, these variables are not even declared as parameters of a function.

So what's the difference between declaring a variable with or without the 'var' keyword?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you don't use it, it *might* be a global variable, or in IE's case, it'll just blow up.

There are cases you don't need it, for example if it's a parameter to the function you're in, it's already declared.  **Always** use `var` in any other cases (other cases being: unless you're manipulating a variable that already exists).  No matter what scope it needs to be defined at, *explicitly* define it there.

Answer (score 15):

It's all about scoping. Technically you can omit var but consider this:

```
myVar = "stuff";

function foo() {
    myVar = "junk"; //the original myVar outside the function has been changed
}

function bar() {
    var myVar = "things" //A new scoped myvar has been created internal to the function
}
```

Comment: You can't "technically omit it", some browsers *allow it*, there's a difference.  IE blows up when you do this, as it should.

Comment: @Nick fair comment, I phrased that wrong

Comment: Oh and by the way I wasn't suggesting that you EVER omit var, I was just saying you can get away with it. Using var makes your code easier to read and debug, get in the habit of using it.