# html/javascript/php: how do i use a "global variable"?

Tags: javascript, php

so my domain name is going to change from building it on my computer (localhost) to what my domain name will be when i actually deploy it, and I don't want to go back and have to change it in a million places. Now i know I could do a superglobal variable in php

`<?php echo $GLOBALS['domain_name']; ?>`

but as far as I know you can't use this in separate .js files. How can I create a "global variable" for my domain name that can be used in html and js?

Comment: As a note, you can create a header file where you declare all your default (PHP) load stuff first, including your domain name. This will help you avoid globals, and it's nicer to have all of that same old functionality seperated.

Comment: Why aren't you using relative links within your pages? Then it doesn't matter where the files are actually located.

Comment: Is it to be a PHP global or a JavaScript global? (HTML has no variables.)

Comment: @jeff: Sometimes relative links are not an option. For example, if you have a layout template that is processed in both `/` and `/foo/bar` URLs, and it contains stylesheet/JS/font/image references, there is no way to do it without absolute links (or counting where your caller code is right now, which is even messier than just knowing your base URL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Print in head of index file (or in php include in header tags)**

Any js file can use variables defined in same scope level above it, even if in other files.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Common form is to, inside the  tag and at before any other  calls, to define all 'global' js variables.

Printing php into a js file is discouraged highly for a few reasons, even though i have heard its possible, but just use a php include if you need it in multiple places:

```
<html>
<?php
  // include any shared content, in this case i include entire <head> section
  include('header.php');
?>
<body>
```

So if you have something like this at top of your php index file, or in an include you place there:

```
<script>
  var baseUrl = "<?php echo $GLOBALS['domain_name']; ?>";
</script>
```

Then that can be used as a standard variable anywhere after that point.

**Side Note: using object wrapper**

As a side note, you could wrap it in an object and pass that object through to other files, such as:

```
var AppData = {};
AppData.domain_name = "<?php echo $GLOBALS['domain_name']; ?>";
AppData.googleTrackerUID = "<?php echo $GLOBALS['gtrackerid']; ?>";
AppData.whatever = true;

fnct_from_earlier_point_or_elsewhere(AppData);
```

Thats only really of use if you think you may need to pass any other settings through, or just want to build for that possibility (especially if optional param, as easy to make reusable function that handles if an index doesnt exist)

I prefer the object approach, but dont overcomplicate if not needed.

**EDIT**

As @Amadan commented, it would even be easier to create the $AppData array/object in php then just call this:

```
var AppData = <?php echo json_encode($AppData); ?>;
```

Also, regarding someone posting to omit the 'var' keyword, its usually bad form as var doesnt stop it being global, and some issues with certain browsers (IE)

[javascript var or not var, what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385894/javascript-var-or-not-var-whats-the-difference)

Comment: As I stated, the object approach is extremely nice and extremely simple if you just write `AppData = <?php echo json_encode($AppData); ?>`; this way, it's less code, you don't care about data types, and it won't break your code if one of your settings happens to contain a double quote.

Answer (score 2):

You can inject any PHP value into clientside.

```
<script>
  var baseURL = <?php echo json_encode($baseURL); ?>;
</script>
```

Use `json_encode` because this gives foolproof safe way of delivering data in the format JS understands, and works on real arrays, PHP "arrays", numbers, strings, whatever you want.

Comment: sure but i want to do it in a separate .js file... does that work?

Comment: In theory, it can, if you execute the JS file using PHP. But you shouldn't. The idea is that in your webpage header you inject the constants all of your JS code will need; your code can remain in the separate JS file. The variable being global (i.e. defined on `window`), means that you can access it from wherever - including from other JS files.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<script>    
window.yourGlobalVariable = ....
</script>
```

by using you window it will be available for all your site

see:
[Define global variable in a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0):

you can have a file like const.php

```
 define('ROOT','http://127.0.0.1/');
```

and than use  everywhere so will only need to change value of ROOT

Answer (score 0):

Never too late!

Usually, it is not a good practice to use php in a js script.

Instead of using ...

```
<script>
var baseURL = <?php echo json_encode($baseURL); ?>;
</script>
```

... you might consider using a *data-* attribute like:

```
<script data-base-url="<?=json_encode($baseURL)?>">
let baseURL = document.currentScript.getAttribute("data-base-url");
</script>
```

Alternatively, you can include the above js code in any separate js script and just add the *data-base-url* attribute to the script tag which inserts this script into your HTML.